# How to documenting datasets for a r-package?

Tags: r, package, cran

I'm trying documenting datasets for a r-package as here http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#documenting-data. Each data consist in single vectors and I wrote in each `data1.R` something like this:

```
#'
#' @format A single vector with one column:
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#'  data1
#' }
"data1"
```

Them, I puted each document ".R" files in the folder `mypackage/R`. But, when I submeted for CRAN, their reported the follows warning:

```
Undocumented code objects:
  ‘data1’ ‘data2’ ‘data3’ ‘data4’ ‘data5’ ‘data6’
Undocumented data sets:
  ‘data1’ ‘data2’ ‘data3’ ‘data4’ ‘data5’ ‘data6’
```

What I did make wrong?

Comment: did you launch package documentation to generate .Rd files?

Comment: I don't generate .Rd files for data files, only for funtions files. I thought that .R files on folder R/ it was quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All package objects should be documented to avoid the warnings.
You should launch :

```
devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))
```

to generate .Rd files associated with your datasets